# can't click the checkout button on shopee using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

Trying click this shopee checkout button. can't continue to the next process. Here's the html element

html :

```
<button class="shopee-button-solid shopee-button-solid--primary " xpath="1"><span class="pcmall-cart_1FvSs2">checkout</span></button>
```

There is a my code:

```
def click(browser,element_css):
    WebDriverWait(browser,60).until(
        ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, element_css)))
    
    WebDriverWait(browser,60).until(
        ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, element_css))
    )
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(element_css).click()


click(browser,'.shopee-button-solid')
wait.until(
    ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.loading-spinner-popup'))
)
```

Error Code python selenium:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="shopee-button-solid shopee-button-solid--primary ">...</button> is not clickable at point (984, 524). Other element would receive the click: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 44 22" class="chat-icon">...</svg>
```

It doesn't work anymore and the button doesn't get clicked. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have used the `explicitWait`

```
check_out = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"")))

check_out.click()
```

So the code can be like

```
check_out = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[7]/button[4]")))

check_out.click()
```

Comment: @anzrocksby84 I think you updated your question